# Help me understand this MySQL code

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$query = "SELECT posts.*
    FROM map, posts, tags
    WHERE map.tag_id = tags.id
    AND (tags.name IN ('mysql', 'database'))
    AND map.post_id = posts.id
    GROUP BY posts.id
    HAVING COUNT( posts.id ) = 2";
```

I don't understand the last row. Can someone please explain it for me? What is the difference if I don't have it there?

Comment: Selecting * when you use GROUP BY is also bad style, as it won't compile on most DBMS and won't have any predictable behavior on MySQL

Comment: BTW, now when you've asked a few of questions and got answers, you may want to mark some of them as "answering" your questions (if any of them do)

Comment: Aside: `SELECT posts.*` is acceptable, because the `GROUP` is on `posts.id`. Assuming that's the primary key, that makes all the other columns in `posts.*` ‘functionally dependent’ on the group column. You only get an error in ANSI SQL when you try to SELECT an unaggregated column that doesn't have a functional dependency on the GROUPing column. You might still argue that any old SELECT * could be bad style, but that's a different matter...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last row says that you leave only those groups having exactly 2 post ids. If you remove it, all groups will be selected.

Comment: Please don't change your question this time so that it becomes completely different

Answer (score 0):

The "HAVING" predicate acts as a filter, which selects only rows with two (2) of the same post.id.

It looks like the query is looking for rows with duplicate IDs.

```
HAVING COUNT( posts.id ) > 1
```

would probably be better for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

The HAVING clause is applied nearly last, just before items are sent to the client, with no optimization. (LIMIT is applied after HAVING.)

So the where clause gets applied, then group by, then having..  Having can apply to values caluclated after your group by has rolled up all your aggregates like SUM or MAX.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html